# error message not showing on password fail

Tags: php, mysql

why is my error message not showing if password or username is incorrect? i would like an error message displayed if the user enters the wrong username or password

code can be seen below

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('connect.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }
    else
    {
    // Invalid login
    echo "Your username or password are incorrect!";
}

        // Jump to secured page
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);

switch ($row['drop']):
    case yes:
        header('Location: choose1.php');
        exit;
    case no:
        header('Location: choose2.php');
        exit;


}
else {

        header('Location: login.php');


}

?>
```

Comment: tips: always write `exit()` just after `header()` ( for your `else` part)

Comment: `why is my error message not showing if password or username is incorrect?` Because it doesn't even try to do that. You can't really detect that with a single simple query. You'll need to add one to check if the username exists, and then another to check if the given password is the correct one for that user.

Comment: using `mysql_real_escape_string` with `md5(password)` is bad idea

Comment: @Seventoes my script does exatly that. if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {

Comment: @diEcho im looking to fix error message not "tips"

Comment: @Jacob : tips is just for your better programming life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write case value in `'` also `break` in switch case

```
case 'yes':
        header('Location: choose1.php');
        exit; // this line shouldn't be needed but it's good practice
        break;

case 'no':
        header('Location: choose2.php');
        exit;
        break;
```

#### better way:

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('connect.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$input_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$input_username."'" );

// Check username and password match
$row = mysql_fetch_array($login);
if (mysql_num_rows($login)) {
        if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])){
             $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
             switch ($row['drop']){
                    case 'yes': header('Location: choose1.php'); break;
                    case 'no': header('Location: choose2.php'); break;
                }
                     exit;
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong username and password combination";
            exit;
        }       
}
else{
        // Invalid login
        echo "Invalid Unsername";
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: thnx but this script does not seem to work. In the browser it shows the page that this is on and nothing is shown

Comment: write `echo"HERE I AM";` between `switch` and `exit;`

Comment: @diEcho Maybe you meant $row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])?

Comment: @diEcho forgot the ; after break. Is there anyway i can display in pop up rather than a new page?

Comment: @diEcho no im trying to learn login script & php. we all have to start somewhere. you learn by asking questions

Comment: @diEcho it would take me hours to find it and seconds for you to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('connect.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
  // Set username session variable
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
else {
  // Invalid login
  header('Location: login.php?try=failed');
  exit;
}

// Jump to secured page
$row = mysql_fetch_array($login);

switch ($row['drop']) {
  case 'yes': header('Location: choose1.php'); exit;
  case 'no':  header('Location: choose2.php'); exit;
}

?>
```

On login.php, check for try=failed:

```
if ($_GET['try'] === 'failed') {
echo "Your username or password are incorrect!";
//echo YOUR_LOGIN_FORM here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to handle your problem.

**Note**: I initialize a `$_SESSION['error']`, just use an `if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) echo $_SESSION['error'];` on your login.php to display the error.

```
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('connect.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . md5($_POST['password']) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if(mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    // Set username session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    // fetch results
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);

    // jump to secured page
    switch($row['drop'])
    {
        case 'yes':
            header('Location: choose1.php');
            exit;
        case 'no':
            header('Location: choose2.php');
            exit;
    }
} else {
    // invalid login
    // set error session
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Your username or password are incorrect!";
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```